# In what context is 50 threads per inch common?

Tags: measurements, threads

I recently found a loupe with a thread pitch reticle displaying common UTS thread pitches... except that rather than 40, 48, or 56 it has a 50. What would this be used for? It doesn't appear to date from earlier than the 1960s - the housing and dioptre lens are plastic, the reticle and retaining ring are glass/metal.

[image: image of thread count reticle]

Answer (score 1):

Fine threads (40 to 120 TPI) are used in adjustable mountings in fields such as optics and mirrors as well as other fields with small parts : watch making etc.

More detail can be found here:
[Fine adjustment screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_adjustment_screw)

Comment: But it's not an extraordinarily *fine* pitch, it's just an unusual one, and in particular seems like an outlier in the included set...

Comment: As pointed out fine is 40 tpi or more ...

Comment: Sure, and 40, 48, and 56 tpi are all fairly common thread pitches in the UTS set to which all the other ones shown belong... 50 tpi is not, hence my curiosity. :)

Comment: Used as specialist or proprietry threads see http://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/antique-machinery-and-history/old-lufkin-tools-determining-difficult-thread-pitches-295276/

Comment: *Whitworth Instrument Thread*: "British fine thread for clocks and optical devices." includes 50 TPI: http://www.gewinde-normen.de/en/whitworth-instrument-thread.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not an engineer but I believe there is a Brown & Sharpe outside micrometer (and perhaps others) with that thread pitch. In this instrument, one revolution of the thimble would traverse 0.020" rather than the more common 0.025". So, you'd need 5 revolutions per 100 thou of travel, or 50 for one inch.  The finer pitch allows you to directly read 0.0001" increments.